# DOM elements reappearing after using jQuery and clone / remove

Tags: jquery

I'm working with jQuery to dynamically add and remove div sections from a form.  I can add new sections but when I go to remove I have these bugs:

1) The "Add" button for the previous section is supposed to reappear (through toggle).  It isn't.

2) I add sections by cloning the previous.  No issues.  I can remove that section, with issue 1.  If I add a section after this process, all the previously removed sections reappear with the additional section.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    $(function () {

    var addDimension = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var clone = parent.clone(true);

        var next = Number(parent.attr('id')) + 1;
        clone.attr('id', next);

        parent.after(clone);

        $(this).toggle();

        $('.add').bind('click', addDimension);
        $('.remove').bind('click', removeDimension);
    }
    // Add a new Dimension to the form for saving
    $('.add').bind('click', addDimension);

    var removeDimension = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var id = Number(parent.attr('id')) - 1;
            alert(parent);
            $('#'+id+' .add').toggle();

            parent.remove().end();
        }
        //Remove dimension
        $('.remove').bind('click', removeDimension);

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7pMe/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in how you are applying event handlers within `addDimension`.

When you use `$('.add').bind` it will affect all elements in page with `class="add"`.

Since you have already bound the click handlers to existing elements of that class you are compounding event handlers.
This means existing elements will fire event for as many times as you add new elements.

The most common approach is to use event delegation to apply handlers to a fixed asset and target existing or new elements.

Using event delegation , remove the `bind` calls inside `addDimension` and change existing ones to this format:

```
$('#dimensions').on('click','.add', addDimension);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W7pMe/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  Always learn something when I venture out and do development in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Three things :

- each time you call the `bind()` method, it attaches (again) the callback to the event. After some adds of dimension, a click on the link 'add dimension' calls several times your function `addDimension()`. It should always be called only once (it explain your second point). Rather use event delegation to manage such cases (see jQuery documentation on the method `on()` and the fiddle below).
- each time you delete a dimension, you display the link 'add dimension' of the previous dimension. It should be the case only if the last dimension is removed.
- I manage your first point by the use of jQuery methods `prev()` and `next()` to navigate in the elements of the class `.dimension`.

Live example at http://jsfiddle.net/W7pMe/4/

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but charlietfl beat you to it for the answer.